# What is the lowest sum of squared errors (sse) of a dataset?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, least-squares, k-means, sums-of-squares

Given $X \subset R^d$ a set of data points, $z \in R^d$ a vector, $SSE(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{|X|}||X_i-z||^2$, I wonder what is the best value of $z$ so that $SSE$ is the lowest?

I suspect that $z$ is the arithmetic mean of $X$ but I'm not sure, I don't see how to prove it.

Thank you in advance for your clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to take the derivative of $sse(X, z)$ wrt $z$ and find its zero:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}sse(X, z) = \sum_{i=1}^{|X|}2 (X_i-z) = 0 \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{|X|} \sum_{i=1}^{|X|} X_i, $$
i.e., the arithmetic mean of $X$, as you suspected :).

Comment: Thank you @JFarias ^^. Exactly the average I suspected. I imagine you considered $||.||$ as the Euclidean distance. What about $z$ if $||.||$ was another distance other than the Euclidean distance?

Comment: You're welcome! So, yeah, I took it as being the L2 norm. There's also the connection between the L0 and L1 norm (absolute value distance) and the mode and median of $X$, respectively! Here's what I mean: http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/03/22/modes-medians-and-means-an-unifying-perspective/. Also, a simple proof for the former:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations-the-l-1-norm. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you!!! I see that $l_0, l_1, l_2$ have a relationship and therefore we could apply the same demonstration to them. What about for example more complex distances such as Dynamic Time Warping (DTW), Mahalanobis, Wasserstein...? –

Comment: Hmm, for sure you can do the same simple procedure as above to compute the case when the distance is Mahalanobis, but I do not know if there are analogous statistics for the Wasserstein and  DTW distances... I'd be very curious if so.